# LaTeX3: Function scope

Tags: latex3, scoping

If I get it right, a token list is declared globally but can be assigned locally. So all local variables with the same name are actually declared globally as the same one. Functions often need to use local variables, and it is difficult to ensure these local variables have no name clash. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_module_my_tl

%%  Example 1: A function group is wanted.

\cs_new:Npn \module_outer:
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_module_my_tl { outer }
    \tl_show:N \l_module_my_tl
    \module_inner:
    \tl_show:N \l_module_my_tl
}

\cs_new:Npn \module_inner:
{{  %%  If you change this to { you'd get wrong result.
    \tl_show:N \l_module_my_tl
    \tl_set:Nn \l_module_my_tl { inner }
    \tl_show:N \l_module_my_tl
}}  %%  If you change this to } you'd get wrong result.

\module_outer:

%%  Example 2: A function group is unwanted.

\cs_new:Npn \module_tokens:
{   %%  If you change this to {{ you'd get wrong result.
    { 1 } { 2 } { 3 }
}   %%  If you change this to }} you'd get wrong result.

\tl_set:Nx \l_module_my_tl { \module_tokens: }
\tl_show:N \l_module_my_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

In the first example of this code, both outer and inner functions use the same token list `\l_module_my_tl`. Unfortunately, the change in the inner function propagates to the outer function, which is unwanted. An easy solution is to add a function-level group for the inner function.

But this function-level group can cause problems if the function has output, as can be seen in the second example. If a function-level group is added, it would output `{{1}{2}{3}}` but not `{1}{2}{3}`.

What would be a general solution (a universal convention that programmers can follow without case-by-case attention) that makes both examples work?

Comment: Please, try and use proper naming of variables and functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “propagates”, I get `outer`, `outer`, `inner`, `outer` and `{1}{2}{3}` as I expected from the code. I don't get what you're after, sorry, but probably it depends on your misunderstanding of braces actions when delimiting arguments (that ***don't*** make groups).

Comment: @egreg What you get is the correct result. That's because I used double bracing. If you change it to single bracing you'd get `outer` `outer` `inner` `inner`, which is wrong. But this double bracing trick doesn't always work, which is seen in the second example. If you change the second example to double bracing, you'd get an additional level of grouping on the result, which is unwanted.

Comment: Why should it be “wrong”? It follows the rules. If you set locally a variable, its value remains the same until another assignment or until the group ends, whichever comes first.

Comment: @egreg The point is, I want the variable scope follows the function scope so that I know variables local assignment won't have an effect outside of the function. The question is about how to align tex groups with function scopes.

Comment: There is nothing such as “function scope”.

Comment: @egreg Right, I know plain tex doesn't have "function scope", only groups. But isn't the point of expl3 to create a higher-level environment that makes programming easier? The function scope is prevalent in many general programming languages but probably hasn't been introduced in expl3. It could be challenging to develop one.

Comment: It's not possible to change TeX.

Comment: @egreg It *may* be possible to make every function has its own group and store its return value into a special token list that is returned to the caller. That creates a function scope aligned with its group scope.

Comment: TeX is a language based on macro expansion; it is not functional.

Comment: TeX is a macro expansion language, so the concept of functions returning values is not available in the language. The "solution" is to name your variables more carefully. Is this a such an impost?

Comment: @Cyker really there are no functions, there are only macros, expl3 helps manage that but it can't change it. Many expl3 commands need to be expandable, and there there is no possibility of using grouping as adding a group would make it non expandable.

Answer (score 4):

In many programming languages such as `Lua`, a function or a condition expression makes a block, and the values of local variables will
be reset after a block. For example

```lua
---- lua code ----
local tmp = "a"
print(tmp)          ---- tmp=a
function SomeFun()
  local tmp = "b"
  print(tmp)        ---- tmp=b
  if 1 > 0 then
    local tmp = "c"
    print(tmp)      ---- tmp=c
  end
  print(tmp)        ---- tmp=b
end
SomeFun()
print(tmp)          ---- tmp=a
```

Recently I wrote [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package based on `expl3`. In this package, you can make every function (also every conditional) become a group by setting `\Functional{scoping=true}`.

```
% --- latex code --- %
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}
\Functional{scoping=true}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\TlSet \lTmpaTl {a}
\TlVarLog \lTmpaTl          % ---- a
\PrgNewFunction \SomeFun { } {
  \TlSet \lTmpaTl {b}
  \TlVarLog \lTmpaTl        % ---- b
  \IntCompareTF {1} > {0} {
    \TlSet \lTmpaTl {c}
    \TlVarLog \lTmpaTl      % ---- c
  }{ }
  \TlVarLog \lTmpaTl        % ---- b
}
\SomeFun
\TlVarLog \lTmpaTl          % ---- a
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\end{document}
```

Although there are functions in `expl3`, the evaluation of them is from outside to inside. With this new `functional` package, the evaluation of functions is from inside to outside, which is the same as other programming languages such as `Lua` or `JavaScript`. Here is another example for calculating square of an integer:

```lua
---- lua code ----
function MathSquare (arg)
  local lTmpaInt = arg * arg
  return lTmpaInt
end
print(MathSquare(5))
print(MathSquare(MathSquare(5)))
```

```
% --- latex code --- %
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MathSquare { m } {
  \IntSet \lTmpaInt { \IntEval { #1 * #1 } }
  \Result { \Value \lTmpaInt }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\MathSquare{5}
\MathSquare{\MathSquare{5}}
\end{document}
```

You will find that there is an almost one-to-one correspondence between `Lua` code and `functional` code. I think this package is what you want.

Comment: Interesting package. Will the functions it makes be expandable?

Comment: @Gaussler They are always protected, since they need to save returned values to a global `tl` and pass to this package. Doing things by expansion is hard and often causes problems. I want to make latex3 programming more like `lua`.

Comment: I understand your point, but if you want LaTeX3 to work like Lua or any other proper programming language, all the functions should be fully expandable, even if they make local assignments.

Comment: @Gaussler No need to be expandable. You may try my package or read the package file.

Comment: @L.J.R. I think the point is with a Lua function you can embed it wherever, and that carries over to `\directlua`, but you can't put a `\protected` macro into say a `\intexpr`.

Comment: @JosephWright It is possible to put the result into a fully expandable macro, by writing like this:  `\TlSet\lTmpaTl{\MathSquare{5}}\the\numexpr1+\lTmpaTl\relax`.

Comment: @L.J.R. Sure, but what you can't do is the equivalent of `\numexpr\directlua{function math.square(x) return x**2 end math.square(5)}\relax`

Comment: @JosephWright True. This package is written mainly for normal users. All programming and calculation should be done with the builtin functions.  It is not a good choice for normal users to use `\numexpr` and its friends.

Comment: That looks an interesting package.  I agree that L3 could do with the option of more traditional functions and have developed my own system in the `spath3` library (and in my attempts at the advent of code).  I suspect there's some overlap of ideas.   Nice to see someone putting it together into a usable package.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I am glad we have similar ideas. :-)